# Show Account information tab as active in admin customer edit page Magento2

Tags: magento2, ui-form, customize

I want to show account information tab as active,

when admin goes to customer edit page. By default it shows customer view tab as active.

I checked Magento Ui module but still no luck. Is there anyone who did this type of customisation.

Appreciate if anyone can help!!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/tab_group.js.

There is one function called which activates first tab by default.

```
/**
 * Activates element if one is first or if one has 'active' propert
 * set to true.
 *
 * @param  {Object} elem
 * @returns {Object} - reference to instance
 */
initActivation: function (elem) {
    var elems   = this.elems(),
        isFirst = !elems.indexOf(elem);

    if (isFirst || elem.active()) {
        elem.activate();
    }

    return this;
},
```

I just changed that condition as I needed like below

```
/**
 * Activates element if one is first or if one has 'active' propert
 * set to true.
 *
 * @param  {Object} elem
 * @returns {Object} - reference to instance
 */
initActivation: function (elem) {
    var elems   = this.elems(),
        isFirst = !elems.indexOf(elem);

    if (elem.index == 'customer' && elem.ns == 'customer_form') {
        elem.activate();
    } else if (isFirst || elem.active()) {
          elem.activate();
    }

    return this;
},
```

Make sure you override this file. Hope it will help others. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I think it will affect all the tabs...Add else condition with default code

Comment: I don't think so it will affect other tabs because at a time only one tab will be activated. But it is good to have else condition.

Comment: Other tabs like order edit page tabs and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Ranganathan, I just updated answer. I will check further if any improvement is there I will update my answer.

Comment: Accept your answer. It will help others